# How to resize an image programmatically in php?

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing, resize-image

I came across few solutions but all those were based on uploading an image. What I want is that it should fetch the image from one folder, resize it of particular size and then save it in other folder.

Comment: Instead of asking us to give code, Google it first, then try it, _then_ ask us a constructive question if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP library function `imagecopyresized()`

Here is a sample programme,

```
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Here is the manual for imagecopyresized().
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: where should i give the destination path? even it prompts an error on header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

Comment: If you are copying code from the manual the least you can do is add a reference to it.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger sorry, i have added it now.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the GD library for this. It works fine. For an example, please see this url: http://runnable.com/UnF-tFdudNt1AABt/how-to-resize-an-image-using-gd-library-for-php